# react router-dom error "No routes matched location"

Tags: reactjs

' No routes matched location "/about" 'errors coming
please help me

**App.js**

```
      <Header/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route path="contents/*" element={<Contents/>}>
          <Route path="about" element={<About/>}/>
          <Route path="offers" element={<Offers/>}/>
          <Route path="booking" element={<Booking/>}/>
          <Route path="guide" element={<Guide/>}/>
        </Route>
        
      </Routes>
```

**Nav.js**

```
...
    <li>
        <Link to="/about">
               <p>1</p>
        </Link>
        ...
    </li>
...
```

**error**

```
No routes matched location "/about"
```

Comment: try to remove slash on link tag

Comment: same, empty page coming :(

Comment: Look for the documentation, `<Outlet/>`

Answer (score 0):

That is because you wrote a nested route for `/about`, since the Route Tag for `/contents` is being closed after the `/about`. The router routes the about page via `/contents/about` and not via `/about` directly. Try to make the contents route self-closing or change the link.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

your path should be like this in app.js

```
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route path="/contents*" element={<Contents/>}>
          <Route path="/about" element={<About/>}/>
          <Route path="/offers" element={<Offers/>}/>
          <Route path="/booking" element={<Booking/>}/>
          <Route path="/guide" element={<Guide/>}/>
      </Routes>
```

Comment: <Contents> Component is not coming :(  I wanna put  about ~ guide component in contents

Comment: then just do this           <Route path="/contents*" element={<About/>}>